# Drawing a font within a Scene within a Screen for Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create an Actor which draws some text to screen. This Actor is within a Screen. My main class is simply:

```
package com.culture.jamiefearon;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class Culture extends Game {
   public SpriteBatch batch;
   public BitmapFont font;

   public void create () {
       batch = new SpriteBatch();
       font = new BitmapFont(); // Use LibGDX's default Arial font.

       // Start the introScreen.
       this.setScreen(new IntroScreen(this));
   }
   public void render () {
      super.render();
   }
   public void dispose() {
      batch.dispose();
      font.dispose();
   }
```

}

And my screen class is defined as:

```
package com.culture.jamiefearon;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class IntroScreen implements Screen {

final Culture game;
OrthographicCamera camera;
private int viewWidth = 800;
private int viewHeight = 480;
private Stage stage;

public class MyActor extends Actor {
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha){
        batch = game.batch;
        game.font.draw(batch, "Culture", viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
    }
}

public void create() {        
    stage = new Stage();
    MyActor myActor = new MyActor();
    stage.addActor(myActor);
}


public IntroScreen(final Culture gam) {
    game = gam;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, viewWidth, viewHeight);
}

public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
}
```

When I run the program the game just crashes.

Comment: is there an error message? if so, can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

You instantiated a Stage without a SpriteBatch, so it creates its own. Then your MyActor ignores that SpriteBatch and tries to use the one from `game`, which hasn't had `begin()` called on it.

Instead, your Stage should be instantiated using the SpriteBatch from `game`, and MyActor should only use the `batch` passed into its draw method.

This might not be the crash you got, but you didn't post your stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

create method of IntroScreen never called so stage is not initialized and used in render method of IntroScreen class.